# iPhone app crashed due to memory pressure while saving recorded video

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am working on the app which capture the video and save in document directory. Later I have to upload that video on `Amazon S3 Server`. But when I am going to stop video recording and save in document directory, the iPhone app crashes due to `Memory Pressure`.

Same code works on iPad without any problem. But it crashes on iPhone and iPod.
Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked there is enough memory left on the device? How large is the video?

Comment: Video is about 1 minute. Is there any limit on document directory storage size?

Comment: You need to provide both the exact and full error message and the code. "Memory Pressure" sound like RAM, not disk related, are you trying to get the entire video in RAM at some point? Also, "1 minute" does not answer "How large is the video", size is in MBs..

Answer (score 0):

"Memory Pressure" sound like RAM, not disk related, are you trying to get the entire video in RAM at some point?

You can not expect to load an entire video into memory ignored to upload it. Instead you need to stream the video most likely using `NSStream` so only a portion is in ARM memory at any time.